# Django: Template should render 'description' not actual value

Tags: django, django-templates

in a Model I have a CharField with choices:

```
class MyModel(models.Model):
    THE_CHOICES=(
        ('val',_(u'Value Description')),
    )
    ...
    myfield=models.CharField(max_length=3,choices=THE_CHOICES
```

Now in the template I access an instance of MyModel:
`{{ my_instance.myfield }}`
Of course the gives me `val` instead of `Value Description`. How do I get the description?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use `{{ my_instance.get_myfield_display }}`, as documented here: http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.1/ref/models/instances/#django.db.models.Model.get_FOO_display